# How to get the value using another column and get difference between each row in MySQL or SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
finish_position    official_rating      date                Difference
    11                   NULL        2013-09-18                 0.00
     4                   NULL        2013-11-08                 0.00
     3                   NULL        2014-02-27                 0.00
     6                    65         2014-04-24                 0.00
    13                    63         2014-05-05                 0.00
     1                    59         2014-07-04                 0.00
     2                    65         2014-08-04       (59-65)= -6.00
    12                    68         2014-10-28       (59-68)= -9.00
     9                    62         2014-12-09       (59-62)= -3.00
     5                    65         2015-01-08       (59-65)= -6.00
     7                    60         2015-01-29       (59-60)= -1.00
    11                    65         2015-04-08       (59-65)= -6.00
     5                    63         2015-04-22       (59-63)= -4.00
     1                    60         2015-07-14                 0.00
     9                    60         2015-08-04       (60-60)=  0.00
     8                    56         2016-01-22       (60-56)=  4.00
     4                    52         2016-02-26       (60-52)=  8.00
     7                    50         2016-03-31       (60-50)=  10.00
     8                    48         2016-04-25       (60-48)=  12.00
     4                    56         2016-07-12       (60-56)=  4.00
     8                    47         2016-09-23       (60-47)=  13.00
     9                    52         2017-06-20       (60-52)=  8.00
     1                    50         2017-07-04                 0.00
     3                    55         2017-07-20       (50-55)=  -5.00
     3                    48         2017-07-29       (50-48)=  2.00
```

I have above two columns(finish_position, official_rating). I want get the above values for the difference column. Whenever finish_position is 1 then difference is 0. All above rows differences are 0 until this row (first row from top to bottom that finish_position is equal to 1) You can get the idea from the above table. I need to get the difference between each rows official_rating between the finish_positions are equal to 1. I hope you guys are understand the problem and please help me to do this.

I want the SQL code.

Comment: What do you want to say with this: >> Whenever finish_position is 1 then difference is 0 << 4 row from above, finish_position is 6 and difference is null ?? Please can you explain in more details ? The table is not logical to me... Also please do tell us what is the order by, do you have id in this table or date column...? Thanks!

Comment: Whenever finish_position is 1 then the difference for that row is reset to 0. And official_rating is NULL that means automatically difference is 0.

Comment: What about the order by ?

Comment: 6th row in the table is the first row that contain finish_position is 1. So above rows differences are 0. At the same time finish_position is 1 then the difference is 0.

Comment: I don't know to do that using order by. You can get the information from the above table. I want to add that difference with above values. So please help me

Comment: I do not know do you understand me, how will we now which row is first and whic is second and so on.... You want us to help you find the difference between a value and its value above that value but we do not know how the data are ordered...

Comment: There is a date column next to the official_rating column. Also all dates are different for the each row

Comment: Show this date column data in your question. Edit the question by pressing edit under the question and add this data to your table...

Comment: Done. Please check the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have imagined to do it like this and I will try to explain.

> Please note that my date column is named datec and table is called
>   test

- First I have selected selected first part of the result where I will not calculate any difference (until first number 1 appeared). I did it with this query:

  ```
  select finish_position, official_rating, datec, 0.00 as difference
  from test
  where datec <= (select min(datec) 
                  from test 
                  where finish_position = 1
  ```
- Then I have selected the second part of the table, where I will calculate the difference and mark it as null because i will calculate the difference in the outer query. The second part is selected with this query:

  ```
  select finish_position, official_rating, datec, null as difference
  from test
  where datec > (select min(datec) 
                 from test 
                 where finish_position = 1)
  ```
- And finally I have made an union of this two results and wrote a query on it:

  ```
  select finish_position,official_rating, datec
         , case when difference = 0.00 then difference
                else official_rating - lag(official_rating) over(order by datec) 
           end difference_1
  from (
  select finish_position, official_rating, datec, 0.00 as difference
  from test
  where datec <= (select min(datec) 
                  from test 
                  where finish_position = 1)
  union 
  select finish_position, official_rating, datec, null as difference
  from test
  where datec > (select min(datec) 
                 from test 
                 where finish_position = 1)) t1
  order by datec;
  ```

Finally I have created a small demo for you (I did not entered whole data but...). [Take a look...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30ee5ffa345c1a1315b3d918f58792b4)

After some more discussion with OP I have finally finished with this code:

```
select finish_position,official_rating, datec
       , case when finish_position = 1 then 0.00
          when t1.datec >= (select tt.datec 
                            from test tt
                            where DATEDIFF(tt.datec, t1.datec) in 
                                  (select max(datediff(ttt.datec, t1.datec))
                                   from test ttt
                                   where finish_position = 1
                                   and ttt.datec <= t1.datec)) 
              then (select t.official_rating 
                    from test t
                    where datediff(t.datec, t1.datec) in 
                          (select max(datediff(ttt.datec, t1.datec))
                           from test ttt
                           where finish_position = 1
                           and ttt.datec <= t1.datec)) - t1.official_rating
              end difference
from (
select finish_position, official_rating, datec
       , case when finish_position = 1 then null
              else 0.00 
         end as difference
from test
where datec <= (select min(datec) 
                from test 
                where finish_position = 1)
union 
select finish_position, official_rating, datec, null as difference
from test
where datec > (select min(datec) 
                from test 
                where finish_position = 1)) t1
order by datec;
```

[Here is the second DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71b09903d607cb200110eeed408bc6f5)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XnsO71yOOzAeNNcd5fDj379tZ3W8l1Az

Please check that folder there is 2 images one image shows the results I got from using your code and other one is shows the result that I want. Please help me. Please ignore the "00:00:00" in the date column. We want only date in that column. I need you to check the difference values from both images. Thanks

Comment: To help you you will have to put there also a image of the code you have done for this calculation. Please upload it as text not the image(the code part). Also are you sure you have used my solution, the image from the other answer is the same yours.... And my solution works great as you can see from my example...

Comment: Hi @ZajjithVedha I have answered your comment.

Comment: When finish_position is 1 then the difference for that row is 0. We need to calculate the difference between official_rating until the next finish_position is 1. I think the fisrt part in your code is correct (until first number 1 appeared).

Comment: You can check the images that are in the drive link.

Comment: @ZajjithVedha I think you do not understand me. Please answer this to me: Have you seen my example ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30ee5ffa345c1a1315b3d918f58792b4

Comment: Hi @ZajjithVedha I have seen where I was wrong in my first code. Now I have updated my answer. Would love to hear back from you to see if it is ok for you. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ZajjithVedha Have you seen my new code ? Have you tried it ?

Comment: I need two more helps from you. So I need to ask another question in stackoverflow? By the way this is the first question.

1. There are 5 columns (name, finish_position, official_rating, date, bsp) in two different tables. 

Table run : finish_position, official_rating
Table price : name, date, bsp

So, can you change your code according to these tables. I want same output. Please....

Comment: Yes, open a new question :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60256275/joining-two-tables-to-get-the-value-using-another-column-and-get-difference-betw

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

Here below is a temporary solution that yields the expected output. *I edited because there were a few conditions I didn't include.*

You can copy the code and paste it at here and run: https://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler

```
WITH LOG AS
(
    SELECT 11 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , NULL AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2013-09-18' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , NULL AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2013-11-08' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , NULL AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2014-02-27' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '65' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2014-04-24' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '63' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2014-05-05' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '59' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2014-07-03' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '65' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2014-08-04' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '68' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2014-10-28' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '62' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2014-12-09' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '65' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2015-01-08' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '60' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2015-01-29' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '65' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2015-04-08' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '63' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2015-04-22' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '60' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2015-07-14' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '60' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2015-08-04' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '65' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2016-01-22' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '52' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2016-02-26' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '50' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2016-03-31' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '48' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2016-04-25' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '56' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2016-07-12' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '47' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2016-09-23 ' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '52' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-06-20' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '50' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-07-04' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '55' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-07-20' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '48' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-07-29' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '58' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-08-15' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '60' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-08-20' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '48' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-08-22 ' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '52' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-08-27' :: DATE AS RATING_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , NULL AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-09-05':: DATE AS RATING_DATE   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '48' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-09-17':: DATE AS RATING_DATE   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '51' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-09-21':: DATE AS RATING_DATE   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '60' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-09-25':: DATE AS RATING_DATE       
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '63' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-09-30':: DATE AS RATING_DATE       
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 14 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '61' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-10-04':: DATE AS RATING_DATE    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '49' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-10-05':: DATE AS RATING_DATE       
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , NULL AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-10-09':: DATE AS RATING_DATE       
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 AS FINISH_POSITION
         , '60' AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , '2017-10-15':: DATE AS RATING_DATE      
)

SELECT T3.FINISH_POSITION AS FINISH_POSITION
     , T3.OFFICIAL_RATING AS OFFICIAL_RATING
     , T3.DATE AS DATE
     , CASE WHEN T3.RATING_OF_1 IS NULL OR T3.OFFICIAL_RATING IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE CAST(T3.RATING_OF_1 AS INT) - CAST(T3.OFFICIAL_RATING AS INT) 
       END AS DIFFERENCE
FROM 
(

    SELECT L.FINISH_POSITION AS FINISH_POSITION
         , L.OFFICIAL_RATING AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , L.RATING_DATE AS DATE
         , L.OFFICIAL_RATING AS RATING_OF_1
    FROM LOG AS L
    WHERE L.RATING_DATE < (SELECT MIN(RATING_DATE) 
                           FROM LOG 
                           WHERE FINISH_POSITION = 1) 
    UNION

    SELECT L.FINISH_POSITION AS FINISH_POSITION
         , L.OFFICIAL_RATING AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , L.RATING_DATE AS DATE
         , L.OFFICIAL_RATING AS RATING_OF_1 
    FROM LOG AS L
    WHERE OFFICIAL_RATING IS NULL

    UNION

    SELECT L.FINISH_POSITION AS FINISH_POSITION
         , L.OFFICIAL_RATING AS OFFICIAL_RATING
         , L.RATING_DATE AS DATE
         , T2.RATING_OF_1 AS RATING_OF_1
    FROM LOG AS L
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT T1.OFFICIAL_RATING_OF_1 AS RATING_OF_1
             , T1.DATE AS DATE
             , LEAD(T1.DATE) OVER (ORDER BY T1.DATE ASC) AS NEXT_RATEING_OF_1
        FROM (
                 SELECT FINISH_POSITION
                      , OFFICIAL_RATING AS OFFICIAL_RATING_OF_1        
                      , RATING_DATE AS DATE
                 FROM LOG
                 WHERE FINISH_POSITION = 1
              ) AS T1
         WHERE T1.OFFICIAL_RATING_OF_1 IS NOT NULL 
    ) AS T2
    ON L.RATING_DATE > T2.DATE AND L.RATING_DATE < T2.NEXT_RATEING_OF_1 
    WHERE OFFICIAL_RATING IS NOT NULL AND T2.NEXT_RATEING_OF_1 IS NOT NULL

    UNION
    SELECT FINISH_POSITION AS FINISH_POSITION
         , OFFICIAL_RATING AS OFFICIAL_RATING       
         , RATING_DATE AS DATE
         , OFFICIAL_RATING AS OFFICIAL_RATING_OF_1
    FROM LOG
    WHERE FINISH_POSITION = 1
) AS T3

UNION 

SELECT L.FINISH_POSITION AS FINISH_POSITION
     , L.OFFICIAL_RATING AS OFFICIAL_RATING
     , L.RATING_DATE AS DATE
     , CASE WHEN OFFICIAL_RATING IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE CAST(T3.RATING_OF_1 AS INT) - CAST(L.OFFICIAL_RATING AS INT) 
       END AS DIFFERENCE
FROM LOG AS L
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           T2.RATING_OF_1
         , T2.DATE AS DATE
         , T2.NEXT_RATEING_OF_1
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT T1.OFFICIAL_RATING_OF_1 AS RATING_OF_1
             , T1.DATE AS DATE
             , LEAD(T1.DATE) OVER (ORDER BY T1.DATE ASC) AS NEXT_RATEING_OF_1
        FROM (
                 SELECT FINISH_POSITION
                      , OFFICIAL_RATING AS OFFICIAL_RATING_OF_1        
                      , RATING_DATE AS DATE
                 FROM LOG
                 WHERE FINISH_POSITION = 1
             ) AS T1
    ) AS T2
    WHERE T2.NEXT_RATEING_OF_1 IS NULL
) AS T3
ON L.RATING_DATE > T3.DATE

ORDER BY DATE ASC
;
```

Output:

[image]

Please note that you will have to remove the `WITH` clause and change the table & column names in order to run against your table. For example, the table I created is called LOG. Also the code is PostgreSQL-based so there are syntax limitations compared to other versions of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of MySQL you are using. In MySQL 8.x you can use the `LAG()` function. For example:

```
select
  *,
  official_rating - lag(official_rating) over(order by date) as difference
from t
order by date
```

See [12.21.1 Window Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html).